# Sum same column in different ways depending on other column - Django ORM

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have the following table assignment structure:

```
| employee | product | process | qty |
| Swati    | PROD1   | issue   |  60 |
| Rohit    | PROD1   | issue   |  30 |
| Rohit    | PROD2   | issue   |  40 |
| Swati    | PROD1   | receive |  40 |
| Swati    | PROD2   | issue   |  70 |
```

I want the final table to look like this for each employee (say for `employee = 'Swati'`):

```
| product | sum_issued | sum_received
| PROD1   |         60 |           40 |
| PROD2   |         70 |            0 |
```

The SQL query which does this is:

```
select product
     , sum(case when process='issue' then qty else 0 end) as sum_issued
     , sum(case when process='receive' then qty else 0 end) as sum_received 
  from assignment 
 where employee = 'Swati' 
 group 
    by product;
```

What should the Django query be, corresponding to this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your Model name is '**Assignment**'. You can use the below query

```
from django.db.models import Case, Value, When, Sum, IntegerField, Count

result = Assignment.objects.filter(employee="Swati").values('product').annotate(
    sum_issued=Sum(
        Case(When(process='issue', then='qty'), default=Value(0), output_field=IntegerField())),
    sum_recived=Sum(Case(When(process='receive', then='qty'), default=Value(0), output_field=IntegerField()))
    )
```

If you print the above query `print result.query` , the result is,

```
SELECT "product", SUM(CASE WHEN "process" = issue THEN "qty" ELSE 0 END) AS "sum_issued", SUM(CASE WHEN "process" = receive THEN "qty" ELSE 0 END) AS "sum_recived" FROM "assignment" WHERE "employee" = 'Swati' GROUP BY "product"
```

Comment: I had tried writing something extremely similar but the query always threw me a FieldError raised by output_field. Thanks!